# X, Y and Z are random variables with the same geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

This question is from Feller's "Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications - Volume 1" and it asks:

> X, Y and Z are random variables with the same geometric distribution $\{q^kp\}$. Find (a) P(X = Y), (b) $P(X \geqslant 2Y)$ and (c) $P(X + Y \leqslant Z)$.

I managed to find part (a) alright. However my question has two parts about the other two parts of the question (b) and (c).

1. For part (b), I achieved the correct answer of $\frac{1}{(1+q+q^2)}$ by doing $$P(X \geqslant 2Y) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}q^{k}p \cdot \sum^{\infty}_{j=2k} q^{j}p = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k}p$$
   and then doing
   $$P(X \geqslant 2Y) + qP(X \geqslant 2Y) + q^{2}P(X \geqslant 2Y) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k}p + \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k+1}p + \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k+2}p$$
   $$P(X \geqslant 2Y)(1+q+q^2) = p(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k} + \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k+1} + \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k+2})$$
   $$P(X \geqslant 2Y)(1+q+q^2) = p(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}q^{k})$$
   $$P(X \geqslant 2Y)(1+q+q^2) = \frac{p}{(1+q+q^{2})(1-q)}$$
   $$P(X \geqslant 2Y) = \frac{1}{(1+q+q^2)}$$
   However, I am confused why this is correct as it seems to miss a lot of scenarios out. For example, what about the scenario where $Y=0$ and $X=1$, which would be the term $qp^{2}$? Or what about the fact that we can get the term $q^{3}p^{2}$ twice (i.e. $(Y=0, X=3)$ and $(Y=1, X=2)$) but the equation would only result in this once? These seem to not be included if using the starting point sum (e.g. $qp^{2}$ would not be a term in $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k}p$ but is a scenario where $X \geqslant 2Y$) so I am confused as to how I have got the right answer.
2. I cannot seem to answer the final part (c). I started with the following $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} (q^{k}p \cdot \sum^{\infty}_{j=0} (q^{j}p \cdot \sum^{\infty}_{n=k+j}q^{n}p))$$ but anyway that I try to simplify it I cannot get the quoted answer which is $\frac{1}{1+q}$. Would anyone be able to explain how to get to this answer?

Thanks

Answers in the book:
[image]

Comment: You say you achieved the quoted answer by "setting $P(X\geqslant 2Y)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^{3k}p$". But isn't that just setting the answer equal to the quoted answer?

Comment: Sorry I said it slightly wrong. I meant I first did $$P(X \geqslant 2Y) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}q^{k}p \cdot \sum^{\infty}_{j=2k} q^{j}p = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k}p^{2}$$ and then did $$P(X \geqslant 2Y) + qP(X \geqslant 2Y) + q^{2}P(X \geqslant 2Y)$$ which led me to get $\frac{p}{1+q+q^{2}}$. Once I had it I check the answer and saw it was right. However, then afterwards I was wondering how it was right.

Comment: Is this what you're looking at when you say that it misses certain outcomes? If so, how are you looking at this and determining which outcomes are/are not being accounted for here?

Also, how did you arrive at this?

Comment: Yes so what I meant was if I wrote out all the possible scenarios I would have something like $$P(X \geqslant 2Y) = P(X=0, Y=0) + P(X=1, Y=0) + ... + P(X=n, Y=0) + P(X=2, Y=1) + P(X=3, Y=1) + ... = p^{2} + qp^{2} + ... + q^{3}p^{2} + q^{4}p^{2} + ...$$ but then I realised that this would be different to $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} q^{3k}p^{2}$. This is why I was confused why I got the right answer when my starting point didn't seem to include all of the terms (e.g. $q^{1}p^{2}$ or $q^{4}p^{2}$, etc.)

Comment: I'm confused by the absence of the terms $P(X=n+1,Y=0)$, $P(X=n+2,0)$, $\ldots$ in your list. Are they implied?

Comment: Apologies, so if $X \geqslant 2Y$ then we this must include the scenario that $X=1$ and $Y=0$ which would have $P(X=1, Y=0) = q^{1}q^{0}pp = qp^{2}$. However,  this term would not be possible in sum that gave the correct answer (i.e. $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}q^{3k}p^{2} = p^{2} + q^{3}p^{2} + q^{6}p^{2} + ...$). So what confuses me is that my starting point which seems to give the correct final answer doesn't match with what I thought would be included in the whole sum. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: My explanation of eyeballing the geometric series and not understanding why they're equal will have two parts.

Recall that for any integer $r$, $\sum_{k=r}^\infty q^kp=q^r\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^kp=q^r$.

We have $$\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant 2Y) = \sum_{y=0}^\infty q^yp\sum_{x=2y}^\infty q^xp=\sum_{y=0}^\infty q^ypq^{2y}=\sum_{y=0}^\infty q^{3y}p.$$

The intuitive sum is $$\sum_{y=0}^\infty \sum_{x=2y}^\infty p^2q^xq^y,\tag{1}$$ while the intuition-offender seems to be $$\sum_{y=0}^\infty q^{3y}p.\tag{2}$$

> Question $1$: Why don't the terms in $(2)$ correspond to individual outcomes?

I believe Question $1$ is what was initially asked, and I addressed it in my pre-edited answer. The summands in $(2)$ are not from individual outcomes such as $X=5,Y=2$. They're from events of the type $Y=y,X\geqslant 2Y$, which have probabilities $q^{3y}p$. So it is easy to analyze $(2)$ and see how the summands are exactly the probabilities of events of this type. In the course of that question, another was raised in the comments.

> Question $2$:
> $$(1)=p^2[q^0q^0+q^0q^1+q^0q^2+\ldots+q^1q^2+q^1q^3+\ldots$$
> and
> $$(2)=p[q^0+q^3+q^6+\ldots.$$ How are these equal?

If you're expecting each summand from $(1)$ to appear exactly once as a summand in $(2)$, and vice versa, you'll be disappointed. We can understand why $$1+1+1+1+1+1=1+2+3$$ holds without a one-to-one correspondence of the summands. The second sum can be obtained by grouping and summing summands from the left side. That's the same thing that happened from $(1)$ to $(2)$. We examing \begin{align*} (1) & = p^2[q^0q^0+q^0q^1+\ldots] \\ & + p^2[q^1q^2+q^1q^3+\ldots] \\ & + p^2[q^2q^4+q^2q^5+\ldots] \\ & + \ldots \\ & = pq^0[q^0p+q^1p+\ldots] \\ & + pq^1[q^2p+q^3p+\ldots] \\ & + pq^2[q^4p+q^5p+\ldots] \\ & + \ldots \\ & = pq^0[q^0]\\ & + pq^1[q^2]\\& + pq^2[q^4] \\ & + \ldots \\ & = p[q^0+q^3+q^6+\ldots]=(2)\end{align*}

As for part $c$, the solution in your book is a typo. Let's just grind:

\begin{align*} \sum_{x,y=0}^\infty q^xpq^yp\sum_{z=x+y}^\infty q^zp & = \sum_{x,y=0}^\infty q^xpq^yp [q^{x+y}] \\ & = \sum_{x=0}^\infty q^{2x}p\sum_{y=0}^\infty q^{2y}p =\Bigl(\sum_{x=0}^\infty q^{2x}p\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{y=0}^\infty q^{2y}p\Bigr) \\ & = \Bigl(\frac{p}{1-q^2}\Bigr)^2 = \frac{(1-q)^2}{(1-q)^2(1+q)^2}=\frac{1}{(1+q)^2}.\end{align*}

I had several others solutions for this before editing, all of which computed the same value. In the interest of reducing confusion, I'll simply note that I tested it with simulations in Python and they agreed with my $1/(1+q)^2$, not $1/(1+q)$. I'll post another answer with another derivation of $1/(1+q)^2$, which hopefully is enough to convince you of a typo.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. However, I am still confused by how $\sum^{\infty}_{y=0}q^{y}p \cdot \sum^{\infty}_{x=2y}q^{x}p = \sum^{\infty}_{y=0}q^{3y}p^{2}$ because $$\sum^{\infty}_{y=0}q^{y}p \cdot \sum^{\infty}_{x=2y}q^{x}p = p^{2}(q^{0}q^{0} + q^{0}q^{1} + ... + q^{1}q^{2} + q^{1}q^{2} + ...)$$ but $$\sum^{\infty}_{y=0}q^{3y}p^{2} = p^{2}(q^{0} + q^{3} + q^{6} + ...)$$. Am I expanding the second incorrectly?

Comment: Also, good spot, I left out the $p^3$ on my question but I had used this is my written workings and the book does say $(1+q)^{-1}$ instead of $(1+q)^{-2}$. I've put the book's answers in an image in the question above

Comment: No, you're expanding it correctly. Are you expecting each term in the first sum to appear exactly once in the second sum, and vice versa? Because they won't. The individual terms in the two sums are not the same, but that's not required for the sums to be the same. The terms $q^0, q^3, q^6, \ldots$ are sums of groups of terms from the other series.

Comment: The second sum should have $p$, not $p^2$.

Comment: Apologies but would you be able to explain how $q^{0}, q^{3}, q^{6}, ...$ are sums of groups of terms from the other series? I'm struggling to prove it myself. Also what do you mean by the "second sum should have p, not $p^{2}$"? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: It's exactly how the sum is grouped: $$\sum_{y=0}^\infty q^yp\cdot \sum_{x=2y}^\infty q^xp \tag{1}$$ is the sum over $y$ of terms of the form $$q^yp\sum_{x=2y}^\infty q^xp=q^yp[q^{2y}]=q^{3y}p,$$ which are the terms of the other sum.

To thing about this as grouping outcomes: $$q^yp\sum_{x=2y}^\infty q^xp = q^ypq^{2y}p+q^ypq^{2y+1}p+q^ypq^{2y+2}p+\ldots$$ is the sum of probabilities of the events $(Y=y,X=2y)$, $(Y=y,X=2y+1)$, $(Y=y,X=2y+2)$, $\ldots$. Group these outcomes into the event $(Y=y,X\geqslant 2y)$, which has probability $$q^yp \cdot q^{2y}=q^yp\sum_{x=2y}^\infty q^xp.$$

Comment: Ah I see it now, thank you much! What I hadn’t clocked was your first identity (e.g. that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=r}q^{r}p=q^{r}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}q^{k}p=q^{r}$. That makes so much sense now as I see how for every Y value the resultant sum of X values greater than or equal to 2Y are just equal to $q^{2y}p$. And also thank you on the typo finding! I had also simplified to that solution but had thought it was wrong due to the book’s answer. Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to provide a few different ways to get these probabilities that avoid geometric series.

Recall that the geometric distribution has the memoryless property, so for any non-negative integer $k$, $X_k:=X-k|X\geqslant k$ has the same distribution as $X$. In particular, $(X_k,Y_l,Z_m)$ has the same joint distribution as $(X,Y,Z)$. So $$\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=\mathbb{P}(X-1=Y-1|X,Y\geqslant 1),\tag{a}$$

$$\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant Z) = \mathbb{P}(X-1\leqslant Z-1|X,Z\geqslant 1),\tag{s}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant 2Y)=\mathbb{P}(X-2\geqslant 2(Y-1)|X\geqslant 2,Y\geqslant 1),\tag{b}$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant Z)=\mathbb{P}(X+(Y-1)\leqslant Z-1|Y,Z\geqslant 1).\tag{c}$$

Part $a$: Split up $$(X=Y)=(X=Y=0)\cup (X-1=Y-1,X\geqslant 1,Y\geqslant 1).$$  Then \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X=Y) & = \mathbb{P}(X=Y=0)+\mathbb{P}(X-1=Y-1,X\geqslant 1,Y\geqslant 1) \\ & = p^2+\mathbb{P}(X-1-Y-1|X,Y\geqslant 1)\mathbb{P}(X,Y\geqslant 1) \\ & = p^2 +\mathbb{P}(X=Y)q^2.\end{align*} We used $($a$)$ at the end. Solving for $$\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=\frac{p^q}{1-q^2}.\tag{A}$$

Similarly, using $($s$)$, since $$(X\leqslant Z) = (X=0)\cup (X-1\leqslant Z-1|X,Z\geqslant 1),$$ so \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X\leqslant Z) & = \mathbb{P}(X=0) + \mathbb{P}(X-1\leqslant Z-1|X,Z\geqslant 1)\mathbb{P}(X,Z\geqslant 1) \\ & = p+\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant Z)q^2, \end{align*}  and $$\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant Z)=\frac{p}{1-q^2}.\tag{D}$$

Part $b$: Split up $$(X\geqslant 2Y)=(Y=0)\cup (X-2\geqslant 2(Y-1),Y\geqslant 1,X\geqslant 2),$$ so \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X\geqslant 2Y) & = \mathbb{P}(Y=0)+\mathbb{P}(X-2\geqslant 2(Y-1)|X\geqslant 2,Y\geqslant 1)\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant 2,Y\geqslant 1) \\ & = p + \mathbb{P}(X\geqslant 2Y)q^3.\end{align*} We used $($b$)$ at the last step. Solving gives $$\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant 2Y)=\frac{p}{1-q^3}=\frac{p}{1+q+q^2}.\tag{B}.$$

Part $c$. Split up $$(X+Y\leqslant Z)=(Y=0,X\leqslant Z)\cup (X+(Y-1)\leqslant Z-1,Y\geqslant 1,Z\geqslant 1),$$ so, using $($c$)$ and $($D$)$, \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant Z) & = \mathbb{P}(Y=0,X\leqslant Z)+\mathbb{P}(X+(Y-1)\leqslant Z-1|Y,Z\geqslant 1)\mathbb{P}(Y,Z\geqslant 1)\\ & = \mathbb{P}(Y=0)\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant Z)+\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant Z)q^2 \\ & = p\cdot \frac{p}{1-q^2} + \mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant Z)q^2.\end{align*} Solving gives $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant Z) = \frac{p^2}{(1-q)^2}=\frac{(1-q)^2}{(1-q)^2(1+q)^2}=\frac{1}{(1+q)^2}.\tag{C}$$